# Delete image in excel sheet with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, image, apache, apache-poi

Need help deleting pictures from sheet.

I've added a few pictures to my excel spreadsheet with the following code:

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
/* Create an anchor point */
XSSFClientAnchor my_anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();
/* Define top left corner, and we can resize picture suitable from there */
my_anchor.setCol1(11);
my_anchor.setRow1(11);
/* Invoke createPicture and pass the anchor point and ID */
XSSFPicture my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, my_picture_id);
/* Call resize method, which resizes the image */
my_picture.resize();
```

Now I want to delete all pictures from the spreadsheet but here I'm stuck.
I found a way to get all pictures from my sheet and save them with this:

```
List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();
for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();
    String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();
    byte[] data = pict.getData();
    if (ext.equals("jpeg")){
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict.jpg")) {
            out.write(data);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't find any methods that deletes pictures and I've search the web without any luck...

Comment: hi, when will the delete picture action be triggered? As in once you have written in the file, later on, how? Also, check this as this is what you'd need to do: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPatriarch.html#clear--

Comment: currently combing the nets for the same information, this is getting quite frustating. Did you find a solution? If so, please share!

Comment: Hey, there **is** a way to do it! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773771/3441504)