# How to remove an image from an excel sheet (XSSF) in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have now been trying for too long to remove an image from my `XSSFSheet`. I cannot find **any** information about this, but I would think that it has to be possible..

Is there any way to remove an image from my `XSSFSheet`? Even the official (?) apache poi website does not mention anything besides [creating and reading images](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images)

I am now not far away from giving up and just copying everything except said image into a new sheet. Which is obviously **not** how this should be done. I don't think I would be able to sleep well for a week if I did that.

My last unsuccessful attempt was to use my code which *moves* images (I shared that code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54767890/3441504)) but instead of setting valid row numbers I would set `null`, but that's not possible since the parameter for `setRow()` is int (primitive type).

Then I tried setting a negative value for the anchor rows. While this technically removes the images, the excel file has to be repaired when it is opened the next time. The images are not being displayed.
I believe I would have to remove the relation from the `XSSFDrawing` too to completely remove the image (I think this after finding [this custom implementation of XSSFDrawing](https://github.com/dataspread/releases/blob/339ece21766e2f70d50872af34cb692a483dc48b/zpoi/src/org/zkoss/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.java#L437)) but I have no idea what is going on there...

I would be grateful for any kind of help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `XSSF` this is not as simple as it sounds. There is [HSSFPatriarch.removeShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPatriarch.html#removeShape-org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFShape-) but there is not something comparable in [XSSFDrawing](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.html).

We must delete the picture itself inclusive the relations. And we must delete the shape's anchor from the drawing.

Example which goes trough all pictures in a sheet and deletes a picture if it's shape name is "Image 2":

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelDeleteImage {

 public static void deleteCTAnchor(XSSFPicture xssfPicture) {
  XSSFDrawing drawing = xssfPicture.getDrawing();
  XmlCursor cursor = xssfPicture.getCTPicture().newCursor();
  cursor.toParent();
  if (cursor.getObject() instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTTwoCellAnchor) {
   for (int i = 0; i < drawing.getCTDrawing().getTwoCellAnchorList().size(); i++) {
    if (cursor.getObject().equals(drawing.getCTDrawing().getTwoCellAnchorArray(i))) {
     drawing.getCTDrawing().removeTwoCellAnchor(i);
     System.out.println("TwoCellAnchor for picture " + xssfPicture + " was deleted.");
    }
   }
  } else if (cursor.getObject() instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTOneCellAnchor) {
   for (int i = 0; i < drawing.getCTDrawing().getOneCellAnchorList().size(); i++) {
    if (cursor.getObject().equals(drawing.getCTDrawing().getOneCellAnchorArray(i))) {
     drawing.getCTDrawing().removeOneCellAnchor(i);
     System.out.println("OneCellAnchor for picture " + xssfPicture + " was deleted.");
    }
   }
  } else if (cursor.getObject() instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTAbsoluteAnchor) {
   for (int i = 0; i < drawing.getCTDrawing().getAbsoluteAnchorList().size(); i++) {
    if (cursor.getObject().equals(drawing.getCTDrawing().getAbsoluteAnchorArray(i))) {
     drawing.getCTDrawing().removeAbsoluteAnchor(i);
     System.out.println("AbsoluteAnchor for picture " + xssfPicture + " was deleted.");
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void deleteEmbeddedXSSFPicture(XSSFPicture xssfPicture) {
  if (xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill() != null) {
   if (xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getBlip() != null) {
    if (xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getBlip().getEmbed() != null) {
     String rId = xssfPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getBlip().getEmbed();
     XSSFDrawing drawing = xssfPicture.getDrawing();
     drawing.getPackagePart().removeRelationship(rId);
     drawing.getPackagePart().getPackage().deletePartRecursive(drawing.getRelationById(rId).getPackagePart().getPartName());
     System.out.println("Picture " + xssfPicture + " was deleted.");
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void deleteHSSFShape(HSSFShape shape) {
  HSSFPatriarch drawing = shape.getPatriarch();
  drawing.removeShape(shape);    
  System.out.println("Shape " + shape + " was deleted.");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filename = "ExcelWithImages.xlsx";
  //String filename = "ExcelWithImages.xls";

  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(filename);

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Drawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();

  XSSFPicture xssfPictureToDelete = null;
  if (drawing instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
   for (XSSFShape shape : ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).getShapes()) {
    if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
     XSSFPicture xssfPicture = (XSSFPicture)shape;
     String shapename = xssfPicture.getShapeName();
     int row = xssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getRow1();
     int col = xssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getCol1();
     System.out.println("Picture " + "" + " with Shapename: " + shapename + " is located row: " + row + ", col: " + col);

     if ("Image 2".equals(shapename)) xssfPictureToDelete = xssfPicture;

    }
   }
  }
  if  (xssfPictureToDelete != null) deleteEmbeddedXSSFPicture(xssfPictureToDelete);
  if  (xssfPictureToDelete != null) deleteCTAnchor(xssfPictureToDelete);

  HSSFPicture hssfPictureToDelete = null;
  if (drawing instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
   for (HSSFShape shape : ((HSSFPatriarch)drawing).getChildren()) {
    if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
     HSSFPicture hssfPicture = (HSSFPicture)shape;
     int picIndex = hssfPicture.getPictureIndex();
     String shapename = hssfPicture.getShapeName().trim();
     int row = hssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getRow1();
     int col = hssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getCol1();
     System.out.println("Picture " + picIndex + " with Shapename: " + shapename + " is located row: " + row + ", col: " + col);

     if ("Image 2".equals(shapename)) hssfPictureToDelete = hssfPicture;

    }
   }
  }
  if (hssfPictureToDelete != null) deleteHSSFShape(hssfPictureToDelete);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

This code is tested using `apache poi 4.0.1` and it needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Will try it out first thing tomorrow, but only by looking at it I know this is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: At the code part `drawing.getCTDrawing().getTwoCellAnchorList()` there I get an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/spreadsheetDrawing/impl/CTDrawingImpl$1TwoCellAnchorList`. I see that the class `CTDrawingImpl` imports `import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTDrawingImpl.1TwoCellAnchorList;` but I can not import this myself because the last part starts with a number which creates a compile error for me. How did you solve this?

Comment: @Cashbee: This code is tested using `apache poi 4.0.1` and it needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025)

Comment: That fixed it! I then had another issue because I did the same process for 2 sheets (in the same workbook) that had the same images to remove. The first removal was successful but the second not. The solution to this was to not call `deleteEmbeddedXSSFPicture` in the second sheet and only call `deleteCTAnchor` there.

Comment: @Cashbee: "The solution to this was to not call deleteEmbeddedXSSFPicture in the second sheet and only call deleteCTAnchor there." Correct. That is because the picture data is stored once per picture on workbook level. And multiple drawing shapes might be related to that picture data. That's why I provided working drafts of two methods. Btw.: That is what all my answers here are: working drafts. And you have correctly used them: Tried understand what the code does and adopt it to the needed use case. Very well.